# notification for file download bad behavior android

Tags: android, notifications

Hello i have class for download file. He work as expected except for remove notification when download is finished. I note what two identical sections of code in effect give different stuff. I mean now I have following behavior: I start download file and I can cancel them by click on notification. Download canceled as expected, the one that must be abort. But if wait until download will finish. Second notification will abort when first will finish and first notification will be stay in notification bar forever. I don't know where my mistake.
Example code:

```
public class DownloadVkVideoFiles extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{
    private static String BROADCAST_ACTION = "com.yourshows.helper.DownloadVkVideoFile.CANCELID";

    public DownloadVkVideoFiles(Context c, String title, int taskId) {
    this.context = c;
    this.notifyId = taskId; //this is unique notification Id
    this.BROADCAST_ACTION += String.valueOf(taskId); //broadcast action for pending intent
    }

   @Override
   protected void onPreExecute() {
        // execute the status bar notification
        createNotification();
        super.onPreExecute();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(BROADCAST_ACTION);
        context.registerReceiver(receiver, filter); //register Receiver for cancel download file
     }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) { //download file}

    @Override
    public void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         notification.contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.progressBar, 100, progress[0], false);
         // inform the progress bar of updates in progress
         notificationManager.notify(notifyId, notification);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        notificationManager.cancel(notifyId); // close finished notification
        unregisterReceiver();
        LOG.send(LOG.I, TAG, "Notification finished with ID = " + notifyId);
    }

    @Override
     protected void onCancelled() {
        super.onCancelled();
        notificationManager.cancel(notifyId);
        unregisterReceiver();

        LOG.send(LOG.I, TAG, "Notification finished with ID = " + notifyId);
    }
}
```

**UPD:**
createNotification:

```
    public void createNotification() {
         notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
         Intent notificationIntent = new Intent();
         notificationIntent.setAction(BROADCAST_ACTION);

         PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, notificationIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

         RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.download_notification);

         // TODO change to shows title
         tickerText = context.getResources().getText(R.string.downloadTitle);
         icon = android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download;
         time = System.currentTimeMillis();

         notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, time);
         notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
         notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
         notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE;

         contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.downloadImage, R.drawable.download);
         contentView.setTextColor(R.id.title, notification_text_color);
         contentView.setFloat(R.id.title, "setTextSize", notification_text_size - 3);
         contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.title, title);
         contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.progressBar, 100, 0, false);

         notification.contentIntent = pendingIntent;
         notification.contentView = contentView;
        //notificationManager.notify(notifyId, notification);
         service.startForeground(notifyId, notification);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried something like that in my project but if you try to download more than 5 files the the download files will behave unexpected the all files damaged.
so i change the structure to Service instead of AsyncTask. 
downloads stored in queue in download one by one the notification bar contain Progress bar number of download and current file name and download percentage.

Comment: i start six tasks at one time, and all they downloaded successfully. But problem is that 5 notification located in notification bar even then download tasks was finished.

Comment: i tried to download 5 files each one around 5 MB most of them damaged.
please append the create notification function.

Comment: Please see my upd. i did have damage files also, but it's my fail. It's happened when i had the same name of files. Files was overwritten each other. Anyway i think really would be more better do this function like you suggested. It allow avoid my problem.

Comment: if you need any help in Service notify me

Comment: I have service already. I started rewriting logic. Thank you.